# str_replace to replace % and spaces with -(dash) at a time

Tags: php, str-replace

how can i replace spaces and % symbol with - (dash) at a time, using str_replace function ?

```
str_replace(' ', '-', $category); 
str_replace('%', '-', $category);
```

this function can only replaces spaces with - (dash) but need to check % sign also and replace it with - (dash) at the same time, how to do so

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
str_replace([' ', '%'], ['-', '-'], '$category,  $category');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
str_replace(array(' ', '%'), '-', $category);
```

learn more about str_replace [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)